# Algorithm to determine sequence of votes needed to reach a score

Tags: algorithm

I have to write some PHP code which determines what possible stackoverflow scores are.

When a user registers he gets 1 point of reputation (lets call this POR).

From here I have to find out what the possible POR values are until the user reaches 100 POR

example:

```
user1 = 1 (registration) + 10 (good answer) - 2 (bad answer) = 9 POR
user2 = 1 (registration) + 5 (good question) + 10 (good answer) = 16 POR
```

The possible choices are:

```
+10 good answer
+5 good question
-2 bad answer/question
```

What I was thinking of doing is:

```
until 100 POR and start from 1
 for all 3 possibilites
  choose a random posibility and append the current score with - and the actual score
 end
end
```

Is there a way to do this which will avoid repetitions?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? By "possibilities", do you mean "probabilities"? If so, that will depend heavily on input distributions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First abstract your problem: You are basically asking for the number of paths in a graph, with 100 nodes as the POR between 1 and 100 and 3 edges from each node (+10, +5, -2).

You might be asking for the number of paths in this graph. Unfortunately, the graph is cyclic (1 good answer, 5 bad answers, and you are back to 1). The answer is thus "infinite".

You might also be asking for the scores that can be reached (the nodes reachable from node 1). You can figure that out on paper, as well, by looking sharply at the combination of one good question and two bad answers.

Comment: 'what are the possibilities of scores on stackoverflow' sounds like finding the reachable nodes, not their paths?

Comment: @Ishtar: Fair enough, that's a possible alternative. Updated.

Comment: +1 : The call out of infinite is superb, although I suspect the teacher hasn't considered it.

Comment: Every node can be reached, since +5,-2,-2 = 1, given you can then repeat that n times and get every number to 100.

Comment: This is actually linear algebra, not graph theory. It's far from graph theory! The question as I understand it is "Which values can the score take", and not "how many possible scores are there". And yes, for the reason andrew posted, the possible values is the entire N

Comment: @MihalisBagos: True. But enlightenment obviously is a function of knowledge presented to the reader divided by time, so we thought presenting two unrelated and much used fields in computer science would result in twice as much enlightenment. :-)

Comment: Hehe, I understand you, +1. Also, judging by the fact that the teacher actually reads SO, I can think of a paper that is going to get nulled!

Comment: oh thanks for the info, i guess that is what my teacher was expecting when he said there's a trick to it thanks